# Keeping track of rng output values

Tags: c#

I've managed a random number generator to model rolling a dice 300 times. Now I want to compare the results to see how truly random it was.

```
class RngPract
{
    public void RunProgram()
    {
       int i;
       Random rollingDie = new Random ();
       Console.WriteLine("Numbers 1 to 6");
       for (i =0; i < 200; i++)
       {
        Console.WriteLine("Next is: {0}", rollingDie.Next(1,7));

       int a = 0;
       switch (rollingDie.Next())
      {
          case 1:
               a++;
               Console.WriteLine("1 appears:{0}",a);
               break;
}
}
}
}
```

I am having trouble getting my switch statement to execute anything.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can store the random generated values in a list and then query the occurrences.

Occurrence of each number can be queried by Grouping by the value, and finding the number of items in each group.

For example,

```
public void RunProgram()
{
   int i;
   Random rollingDie = new Random ();
   Console.WriteLine("Numbers 1 to 6");
   var list = new List<int>();
   for (i =0; i < 200; i++)
   {
       var newItem = rollingDie.Next(1,7);
       list.Add(newItem);
       Console.WriteLine("Next is: {0}", newItem);
   }
   foreach(var item in list.GroupBy(x=>x))
   {
        Console.WriteLine($"{item.Key} {item.Count()}");
   } 

}
```

If you need to provide a live update (each time random generates a number) of the occurance, you could do the following.

```
public void RunProgram()
{
   int i;
   Random rollingDie = new Random ();
   Console.WriteLine("Numbers 1 to 6");
   var list = new List<int>();
   for (i =0; i < 200; i++)
   {
    var newItem = rollingDie.Next(1,7);
    list.Add(newItem);
    Console.WriteLine("Next is: {0}", newItem);
    var occurance = FindOccurance(list,newItem);
    Console.WriteLine($"{newItem} has occured {occurance} times");
   }

}

public int FindOccurance(List<int> list,int currentItem)
{
    return list.Count(x=>x == currentItem);
}
```

Comment: That was a rather unique way of doing it that I hadn't learned entirely yet. Thank you for sharing your input!